# Close modal on button click Elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I hope you are having a nice day.
I am working with the following menu:

[image]

The site with which I am working is a Single Page, I need that when clicking any of the buttons that work as anchors to different sections (referenced by ID) they also close this popup. Any idea how to do it? I can work perfectly with JS and jQuery, I know these technologies a lot.

Thanks for reading and giving me your time. I await your responses. Greetings.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

I have this working for me:

- give the buttons on your popup an additional class of 'close-popup'
- add an HMTL widget to your popup with the following

  ```
  <script> 
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event ) {
        elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( {}, event );
     } );
   } );
  </script>
  ```

I'd like to be able to claim the credit for this, but it goes to [shilo-ey](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/7085)